# Spark run job in parallel. How to pass parameter for `sc.parallelize()`?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following code to

1. Get a list of IDs from an SQL Server function
2. For each ID in the list, get some data from SQL server and output a text file in parallel.

However, how to pass parameters to `doWork.run()` when it's called by `sc.parallelize()`? And is there a better way to organize the code? (`sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options` has been repeated and it seems a code smell)

```
object ConnTest extends App {
  override def main(args: scala.Array[String]): Unit = {
    super.main(args)

    val date = args(0)

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf.setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[*]"))
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val jdbcSqlConn = "jdbc:sqlserver://......;"

    val listJob = new ItemListJob(sc, sqlContext, jdbcSqlConn)
    val list = listJob.run(date) // Return a list of IDs

    val doWork = new DoWork(sc, sqlContext, jdbcSqlConn)
    // ??? How to run doWork for each ID in `list`?
    val processed = sc.parallelize(doWork.run(...id, date...)) 
  }
}

class ItemList(sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, jdbcSqlConn: String) {
  def run(date: LocalDate) = {
    sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
      "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
      "dbtable" -> s"dbo.GetList('$date')"
    )).load()
  }
}

class DoWork(sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, jdbcSqlConn: String) {
  def run(id: Int, date: LocalDate) = {
    // Do work, read data from Sql Server and generate a text file for id
    val data = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
      "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
      "dbtable" -> s"someFunction('$id')"
    )).load()
    // output data to a text file
    (id, date) // return id, date after it's done
  }
}
```

Comment: This just cannot work in Spark. It is boring to repeat but distributed contexts cannot be nested. If you want to achieve driver level parallelism use threads.

Comment: What did you mean "nested"? The list of ID can be a constant list too.

Comment: Scratch that. Actually I have no idea what you're trying to do here. Since `DoWork.run` returns `(Int, date)` this wouldn't even type check. In general (I guess this is what you really want) you cannot `sqlContext.read` inside `parallelize`.

Comment: I made it work. However, I got a new problem and posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121446/spark-application-got-the-error-of-task-not-serializable.

Comment: Ditto. This is not a valid Spark code.