# Spark application got the error of "Task not serializable"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following code got the error of "Task not serializable"?

**The error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)
        at ConnTest$.main(main.scala:41)
        at ConnTest.main(main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: DoWork
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: DoWork, value: DoWork@655621fd)
        - field (class: ConnTest$$anonfun$2, name: doWork$1, type: class DoWork)
        - object (class ConnTest$$anonfun$2, )
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
        ... 20 more
```

**Code:**

```
object ConnTest extends App {
  override def main(args: scala.Array[String]): Unit = {
    super.main(args)
    val date = args(0)
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf.setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[*]"))
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val jdbcSqlConn = "jdbc:sqlserver://......;"

    val listJob = new ItemListJob(sqlContext, jdbcSqlConn)
    val list = listJob.run(date).select("id").rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[Int]).collect() 
    // It returns about 3000 rows

    val doWork = new DoWork(sqlContext, jdbcSqlConn)
    val processed = sc.parallelize(list).map(d => {
      doWork.run(d, date)
    })
  }
}

class ItemList(sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, jdbcSqlConn: String) {
  def run(date: LocalDate) = {
    sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
      "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
      "dbtable" -> s"dbo.GetList('$date')"
    )).load()
  }
}

class DoWork(sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, jdbcSqlConn: String) {
  def run(id: Int, date: LocalDate) = {
    // ...... read the data from database for id, and create a text file
    val data = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
      "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
      "dbtable" -> s"someFunction('$id', $date)"
    )).load()
    // .... create a text file with content of data
    (id, date) 
  }
}
```

**Update:**

I changed the `.map()` call to the following,

```
val processed = sc.parallelize(dealList).toDF.map(d => {
  doWork.run(d(0).asInstanceOf[Int], rc)
})
```

Now I got the error of

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for java.time.LocalDate
- field (class: "java.time.LocalDate", name: "_2")
- root class: "scala.Tuple2"
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:602)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:596)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:587)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is in the following closure:

```
val processed = sc.parallelize(list).map(d => {
  doWork.run(d, date)
})
```

The closure in `map` will run in executors, so Spark needs to serialize `doWork` and send it to executors. `DoWork` must be serializable. However. I saw `DoWork` contains `sc` and `sqlContext` so you cannot just make `DoWork` implement `Serializable` because you cannot use them in executors.

I guess you probably want to store data into database in `DoWork`. If so, you can convert RDD to DataFrame and save it via `jdbc` method, such as:

```
sc.parallelize(list).toDF.write.jdbc(...)
```

I cannot give more suggestions since you don't provides the codes in `DoWork`.

Comment: Thanks. The function `DoWork.run()` will read data from the database and generate text files. I haven't started to write the code of the function body yet.

Comment: Just realized I don't need `sc: SparkContext` for the two classes. I've updated the question. However, I will still need sqlContext to read the database?

Comment: Will dataframe help for my case? Or I had to pre-create parquet files and use Spark-SQL to get the data and create the text files?

Comment: You cannot use `SQLContext` or `SparkContext` in executors. You have two options here: use the JDBC APIs to write your data, or just use `DataFrame.write.jdbc`. In addition, there is one thing I don't get in your codes. Why do you need to convert DataFrame to RDD?

Comment: The reason I convert DataFrame to RDD is to get a list of int so it can be passed to `sc.parallelize()`. Maybe there is a better way to do it? I guess I will have to use JDBC (I only need to read the data from the database and then write it to a text file)?

Comment: Then why do you need to use `sc.parallelize()`?

Comment: The code will generate a text file for each ID in the list. I want to the reading data and generating text files be run in parallel.

Comment: Why you cannot just use Dataset/DataFrame to do everything? If you want to create more partitions, you can just use `repartition`. Not need to collect to driver then call `parallelize` which is ineffective.

Comment: I don't know how to use dataset/df to do everything try. Do you mind to post a simple example using only dataset?

Comment: Which RDD method do you want to use? Dataset has `map`, `foreach`, etc. You should be able to find an altertive method in Dataset.

Comment: Maybe map, because I think I will need to write the IDs returned by the doWork.run() to database for logging.

Comment: I got what you mean. I don't need to convert the result of my first query from data frame to list and then call parallelize(). Data frame is already distributed and will be run in parallel. I'm developing on a eight core machine, will it also run eight processes like parallelize()?

Comment: It depends on how many partitions it has. There are multiple `jdbc` methods in DataFrameReader, and they provide different ways to partition the data. If it's not sufficient, you can also use `Dataset.repartition` to split the data by yourself. Generally, one partition means one Spark task, and one task will use one core.